# Why am I intermittently getting a "No overload for method takes 2 arguments?"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

So I'm working on editing code from a predecessor and I wrote an overload for a method. The method is `TryGetValue` that takes three arguments: a `string`, a `out long`, and a `long`. It was previously also overloaded with `string`, a `out string`, and a `string`.

I added three overloads for it: One taking two arguments: a `string`, and a `out long`. Another taking a `string` and a `out string`. Final one taking a `string` and `T`, a generic.

They all work. However, Visual Studio will sometimes give me the error after I tell it to Build, saying that "No overload exists for method 'TryGetValue' that takes 2 arguments."

However, when I open the class that contains the methods, the error goes away for a while, even after I close the class.

I tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding the solution. It still comes back after a while.

The call: `bool foo = id.TryGetValue("key_id", out keyid);`

where `keyid` is a `long`. `id` is a `DictionaryID` that contains the `TryGetValue` methods.

One of the original methods:

```
public bool TryGetValue(string key, out long value, long defaultValue)
{
    // do stuff
    return true;
}
```

and one of the overloads:

```
public bool TryGetValue(string key, out long value)
{
    return TryGetValue(key, out value, 0);
}
```

Like I said, it works like I expect, but VS will sometimes tell me it can't find it.

Comment: Did you try closing and re-opening Visual Studio?  Our intern has a slow computer and gets stuff like this periodically

Comment: You'd be surprised at how often fully restarting VS fixes these weird behaviors.

Comment: Well, I came back into the office after the weekend, and it seems to have gone away. :/